(Under Windows 10 system) How to find the base address of the .so file in the Android emulator?
(Under Windows 10 system) How to find the base address of the .so file in the Android emulator? Or how to scan data in Android emulator to get the base address or static pointer of that data?
Use python or C++ to implement the above functional operations
